# Conversion of objects attributes to and from pointers as function argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, methods

My function in c contains objects node, with two attributes Key* a pointer to a key object and int data. The signature of a method is key_comp(key, key), which requires two keys, however the node object contains a pointer to a key. I have tried using node->key and (Node).key however neither work as arguments for this method, how would you go about converting the key pointer to a key for use in a method?

```
typedef struct 
{
    Node tree_nodes; 
    unsigned char *is_free; 
    int size;
} BStree_struct; 

typedef BStree_struct BStree;

void insert_helper(int i, BStree bst, Node node){
  if (i>= (*bst).size){
    printf("Out of the range of the tree. \n");
      return;
  }
  if ((*bst).is_free[i]==1){
    (*bst).tree_nodes[i] = node;
    (*bst).is_free[i] = 0;
  }else if (key_comp(bst->tree_nodes[i].key, node.key) >0){
    insert_helper(2*i,bst,node);
  }else if (key_comp(bst->tree_nodes[i].key, node.key) <0){
    insert_helper(2*i+1, bst, node);
  }
}

typedef struct {char *name; int id;} Key;
typedef struct {Key *key; int data;} Node;
Key *key_construct(char *in_name, int in_id);
int key_comp(Key key1, Key key2);
void print_key(Key *key);
void print_node(Node node);

typedef struct {Node *tree_nodes; unsigned char *is_free;
int size;} BStree_struct;
typedef BStree_struct* BStree;
BStree bstree_ini(int size);
void bstree_insert(BStree bst, Key *key, int data);
void bstree_traversal(BStree bst);
void bstree_free(BStree bst)
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question, it sounds like you can just use `*(node->key)`, but it's hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: added the code here is the method, the node contains object of a pointer to a key, however I keep getting errors when compiling

Comment: What are `BStree`  and `Node`?  Pointers?  Please update your question with this information.

Comment: I tried the code you suggested and recieved error, invalid argument type of '->' I added the header files from the two files to the question for supplementary information, I will also add the key_comp method

Comment: This data organisation makes very little sense. Are these types and signatures given to you?

Comment: the two declarations of prototypes below are header files from the two files data and bst.c, the pointer issue works however im getting a segmentation fault, need to troubleshoot that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with.  It's not clear to me exactly what the code is doing, but having a mix of pointers and object copies is throwing it off a bit.

The key thing to consider is that `Node.key` is a pointer (to a `Key`).  So to pass these to `key_comp(Key a, Key b)` you need to de-reference it, thereby converting a `Key*` to a `Key`.

```
void insert_helper(int i, BStree bst, Node node)
{
    if (i >= bst.size)
    {
        printf("Out of the range of the tree. \n");
        return;
    }
    if (bst.is_free[i] == 1)
    {
        bst.tree_nodes[i] = node;
        bst.is_free[i]    = 0;
    }
    else if (key_comp(*(bst.tree_nodes[i].key), *(node.key)) > 0)
    {
        insert_helper(2*i, bst, node);
    }
    else if (key_comp(*(bst.tree_nodes[i].key), *(node.key)) < 0)
    {
        insert_helper(2*i+1, bst, node);
    }
}
```

If it were my code, I'd change `key_comp()` to take a pair of pointers to `Key`.